# how can view added property(added in xml file) graphically in model editor:

Tags: xml, uml, modeling, papyrus

as we know uml diagram represented in xml format so i create class diagram using Papyrus with one class and this class with two property and one operation and then i try to edit xml file in text editor of Papyrus to add another property manually as xml format
 but when i display the class in model editor nothing added ?
why the property not added to class?

Comment: It is possible that papyrus a) keeps the model in memory - restart papyrus to ensure reloading or b) it has an additional place to store the actual diagram (positions, visibility) and you need to edit that one as well (possibly in an annotation in the diagram file.

Comment: thank you so much @Christian i only edit uml file i not made any modifications to annotation file.how can i modify the annotation file?

Comment: You don't need to restart Eclipse. The plugin does not automatically display new elements added within the property view in the graphical editor. See my answer below for changing what is displayed or not

Answer (score 0):

right click on your class in the graphical editor, then hit F4 : you will have a dialgo menu that show what field/method/inner class is displayed or not.